# jQuery sidebar two clicks doesnt load script again

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, load, sidebar

I'm busy with a sidebar and the menu is looks like this

**#warmtepomplijst**

- Brand 1
- Brand 2

**#Soorten**

- Type 1
- Type 2

Now I made with jQuery.load that a part of the website refresh

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".filter_merklink" ).click(function(e) {
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#warmtepomplijst" ).load( link + " #warmtepomplijst", function(e) {
            console.log( "Nieuwe producten zijn opgehaald. Link= " + link );
        });
        $( "#sidebar" ).load( link + " #sidebar", function(e) {
            console.log( "Sidebar opgehaald!" );
        });
    });

    $('#merken a').click(function(e){
        $("#merken a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#soorten a').click(function(e){
        $("#soorten a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

});
```

The first click works fine! So you click on #warmtepomplijst > a and the div#warmtepomplijst refresh with the new products.

The second click if you click on #Soorten > type 1 than the page refresh

---

And if you first click is #Soorten > type 1 it works, and else second step #warmtepomplijst > Brand 1 it refresh.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change all .click methods to .on method. like this :

```
$('#soorten a').click(function(e){...
```

//changed

`$(document).on('click','#soorten a',function(e){...`